# Saving Constructed Means in a Matrix in Stata

Tags: loops, matrix, stata

Have `sales` and a `time` indicator as such:

```
time    sales
  1       6
  2       7
  1       5
  3       4
  2       4
  5       7
  4       3 
  3       2
  5       1
  5       4
  3       1
  4       9
  1       8
```

I want the mean, stdev, and N of the above saved in a t (each time period has a row) X 4 (time period, mean, stdev, N)  matrix.

For time = 5 the matrix would be:

```
time    mean   stdev  N
 ...     ...    ...  ...
  5       4      3    3
 ...     ...    ...  ...
```

Just for the mean I tried:

```
mat t1=J(5,1,0) 
forval i = 1/5 {
    summ sales if time == `i'
    mat t1[`i']=r(mean) 
    }
```

However, I kept getting an error. Even if it worked I was unsure how to get the other (stdev and N) variables of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably aiming for something like

```
matrix t1 = J(5, 1, .) 
forvalues i = 1/5 {
    summarize sales if time == `i'
    matrix t1[`i', 1] = r(mean) 
}
matrix list t1
```

**U[14.9] Subscripting** specifies you need *matname[r,c]*. You were leaving out the second subscript. In Mata you are allowed to subscript vectors in this way but you never enter Mata.

An alternative is

```
forval i = 1/5 {
    summarize sales if time == `i'
    matrix t1 = (nullmat(t1) \ r(mean))
}
```

With the latter, you have no need of declaring the `matrix` beforehand. See `help nullmat()`.

But it's probably easiest to use `collapse` and get all information in one step:

```
clear all
set more off

input ///
time    sales
  1       6
  2       7
  1       5
  3       4
  2       4
  5       7
  4       3 
  3       2
  5       1
  5       4
  3       1
  4       9
  1       8
end

collapse (mean) msales=sales (sd) sdsales=sales /// 
    (count) csales=sales, by(time)

list
```

Note that `count` counts  nonmissing observations only.

If you want a `matrix` then convert the variables using `mkmat`, after the `collapse`:

```
mkmat time msales sdsales csales, matrix(summatrix)
matrix list summatrix
```

Comment: This is great, I do not need a matrix. Is there a way to export it out into a separate database with collapse? The real file gives an output too large for copy and paste. Lastly, with collapse if I want to test if each period is different than zero using a ttest can I add that to your function?

Comment: The help for `collapse` answers most of these extra questions. `collapse` produces a new dataset. It produces summary statistics only, so your associated t-tests would need to be done otherwise.